# Function running even though it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I've got an element. After user click it, it gets activated and depending on the next click user get's the message that he succeeded or not. In both cases the item gets deactivated after the click.

However, even though I sucesfully change the item state to "false" which should stop the code from running it keeps running over and over again. Here is the code:

```
handleBoltcuttersClicked(){
    this.props.dispatch(activate('boltcutters', true));
    console.log('klik');
    setTimeout(() => this.chainMechanics(), 100)

}

chainMechanics(){
    if(this.props.inventory.activeItem.boltcutters===true){
        let clickedElement;
        window.onclick = ((e)=>{
            clickedElement = e.target;
            if(clickedElement.id === 'chainChainedDoor'){
                alert('you got it');
                this.props.dispatch(activate('boltcutters', false))
            } else {
                this.props.dispatch(activate('boltcutters', false));
                alert('try again')
                console.log(this.props.inventory.activeItem.boltcutters);
            }

        })
    }  
}
<a className="ghost-button items" href="#" onClick={() => this.handleBoltcuttersClicked()}>Boltcutters</a>
```

The part  being looped is the whole `window.onclick` function. Even though it shouldnt be accessible, because boolean is no longer true it still works and I cant figure why.

Bonus question:
As you can see I delayed the chainMechanics function with setTimeout, because apparently the store wasn't updated quick enough before the function fired and it didnt work. It started working only after second click (and it didnt work properly, because the window.onclick function got fired immediately on the 2nd click on the item which shouldnt be possible)

Comment: At first I would simplify the code and get rid of the timeout by using React Lifecycle methods. When you dispatch an action, the component gets updated with new props. Use the method componentWillReceiveProps to trigger `chainMechanics`, for example when your `activeItem.boltcutters === true`. And why not using event listeners so you can disable them instead of a global `window.onclick`?

Comment: Or, could you create a live example ? Either using the code snipper provided here or with this tool ? https://codesandbox.io/s/new

Comment: Adding onclick on every clickable element would be ridiculous amount of work, if thats what you meant. Ill try to recreate this example soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, it's not nice, it's ugly, but it works. I added id to the button, and on second click on the boltcutters the "else if" check is being fired preventing state change of the boltcutters themselves allowing the app to get id of proper element and work correctly.

If anyone has more elegant way to deal with this, I am open to suggestions.

```
    chainMechanics(){
    let clickedElement;
    window.onclick = ((e)=>{
        console.log(clickedElement, 'clickedelement', this.props.inventory.activeItem.boltcutters)
        if(this.props.inventory.activeItem.boltcutters===true){
            clickedElement = e.target;
            if(clickedElement.id === 'chainChainedDoor'){
                alert('you got it');
                this.props.dispatch(activate('boltcutters', false))
            } else if(clickedElement.id === 'test'){
                console.log('Why wont you cooperate')
            } else {
                this.props.dispatch(activate('boltcutters', false));
                alert('try again')
                console.log(this.props.inventory.activeItem.boltcutters); 
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you execute this: `window.onclick = ((e)=>{})`, an event listener is registered on the window. From now on the window listens to any click event on the itself and execute the given function once it is clicked. This process is independent of the code before or after the registration.

So you have two options to solve this:

- Either you remove the event listener after checking for the elementID (`window.removeEventlistenter('click', functionName)`). This will only work if the function given when adding the listener already has a name and is not inline like in your case. For details have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener
- Or you make your boolean check within the second click handler. Thus you prevent the actual code from executing and you do not have to deal with adding/removing event listeners. I would recommend this solution.

Let me know whether this helps or if anything is unclear.

**Edit**

```
chainMechanics(){
    let clickedElement;
    window.onclick = ((e)=>{
        if(this.props.inventory.activeItem.boltcutters===true){
            clickedElement = e.target;
            if(clickedElement.id === 'chainChainedDoor'){
                alert('you got it');
                this.props.dispatch(activate('boltcutters', false))
            } else {
                this.props.dispatch(activate('boltcutters', false));
                alert('try again')
                console.log(this.props.inventory.activeItem.boltcutters);
            }
        }
    })
}
```

**Edit 2**

```
function myFunc(e) {
     let clickedElement;
     if(this.props.inventory.activeItem.boltcutters===true){
            clickedElement = e.target;
            if(clickedElement.id === 'chainChainedDoor'){
                alert('you got it');
                this.props.dispatch(activate('boltcutters', false))
            } else {
                this.props.dispatch(activate('boltcutters', false));
                alert('try again')
                console.log(this.props.inventory.activeItem.boltcutters);
            }
        }
}

chainMechanics(){
    if (window.onclick !== myFunc) {
        window.onclick = ((e)=> myFunc(e))
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain your second solution? I don't think I get it but it sounds doable and simple and would love to try it

Comment: So I added 'if(this.props.inventory.activeItem.boltcutters===true){rest of the code}' right after the window.onclick and it stopped executing after first click, however, when I click on the item again, activating whole function again it's not working as intended, it fires alert of "try again" right when I click the item itself, not giving the chance to click on anything else. I'm really confused at this point. I did some console.logs and found out its the window.onclick that wont stop going and constantly registering things

Comment: I don't know if I get your problem correctly. I created a short [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ufebdc64/) . Could you please have a look at it and say whether this works as you would expect it?

Comment: http://crowstorm.pl/nohome/dead/dead.html#   Here i have this thing working in pure JS, but you can see what I meant. You need to click the arrow down, then in new screen the second door to the right and under the bed you have to click boltcutters. Button will appear on the left side and then you can see how it's supposed to work. You will see that it deactiavtes after clicking something and you can easly activate it again. Hope that helps, I think it's gonna be clearer than me making some simpler example in JS fiddle. Lemme know if that helps

Comment: ok, I understand now. Thanks for the clarification.I added a short snippet above. Did you try this? And if it does not work, could you please check whether the boolean is correctly set?

Comment: Yea, sadly I tried the exact same thing and other configurations, it doesnt work. It indeed stops from "looping" but now it works this way:
1. First clicked after clicking boltcutters works properly. 
2. But lets say user clicked wrong item with it and want to try again. Click boltcutters again and IMMEDIATELY "try again" alert pops up, consuming the click event I suppose, because the clickedElement var is still containing the previous element and boolean check passes with previously clicked element. Thought of deleting clickedElement after id check, but u cant delete variables.

Comment: Oh, and booleans are working correctly, there is no problem with that at this point. Main issue seems to be inability to stop this window.onclick after the id check. But cant figure out how to stop this event declared this way.

Comment: Perhaps you have multiple event listeners. So every time a user clicks, a new one is registered. I added a second edit above. Could you please try this? It should only register the listener if it has not been done before.

Comment: Your solution is something I didnt try before, tried it now and sadly there is no change in the behaviour. I really appreciate you trying to help, though. It's the first time Im actually encountering something that doesnt make this much sense. Thing is I see no other similiar mechanics I could implement without adding onClick events on every element on the screen or just to the target element, but that might be counterintuitive when user doesnt get response that he's doing something wrong. Can you think of any other way to detect which element is clicked without using 'window'?

Comment: Mhh.. thats really odd. I am slowly running out of ideas. Especially since it does work for me in the fiddle. So my guess is that the reason is somewhere in your system. Extra odd is that the booleans are be ok. Because then it should not matter that the listener is executed again, the program should pass the IF-statement.
I don't think that there is way without using window or adding a listener on every element.

Comment: I will try some "ugly" code solutions, because I am pretty sure the problem is within the clickedElement var, which is not deleted, and even if null or undefined fires the ID check immediately after clicking boltcutters for the second time, because it still rememembers the last clicked element. Maybe some tricky if statements dealing with undefined cases + adding some counter to the clicks can solve this. If I come up with something I will update. Again, thank you for trying!

Comment: Well, I fixed it, answer is below. It's disgusting, but it works... I don't know how it's gonna work when I add more buttons with similiar mechanics, but for now I can finally test more things.